# Blank submission spam bot

Tags: jquery, forms, captcha, spam

I'm trying to come up with ways of battling a spam bot that just submits my form with blank entries.

My form uses JQuery to check if the fields have been filled out, and to check if the email field has been filled out correctly. However this spam bot is managing to get around this (by disabling JavaScript?) and is able to submit a completely blank form. So what I need is a way to stop this but the issue here is that I can't use any kind of captcha plugins that i'm finding online etc because I can't use PHP, so I would need client side verification on whatever it is I could use to combat it but then my other question is if this spam bot is able to disable JavaScript then surely any kind of measures I put in, for example a honeypot captcha or disabling the form for 5 seconds when the page loads, wouldn't work because of the JavaScript just being turned off and once again this spam bot just bypassing everything and completing a blank submission.

Comment: The answer is simple: You *can't* battle bots with pure client-side verification. You *need* some sort of verification on the server, because in general, you must assume that the client is in full control of any code running in the browser, and that it can choose to replace any verification code you have in the browser with its own, automatic verification.

Comment: Use an easy captcha system, without images, like two random numbers generated in javascript. If the sum of these numbers is correct, submit the form. To prevent the submit with javascript disabled, just omit the action uri until the form is been filled, then append the action by javascript too before submit the form. Anyway you must validate all on server side. The correct is to do two validations (1 in front, 1 in back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to bypass spambot from posting blank entry without adding captcha plugin/image etc.

**Option #1:**

With normal captcha we force user to fill captcha value and validate the same in server side when form is posted but with this trick we will go reverse way.

By default, all spambot access site with javascript disabled. And they are normally coded to fill all form fields.

So what you can do is add one hidden field in form with any name, let's say "**hidden_captcha**".

Now your server side code would be like, if that hidden field is filled then that entry is posted by spambot because normal visitor can not see your hidden field and submit data.

Spambot just look for fields in form and submit the same.

This way you don't need to add captcha plugin/images and filter all entries posted by spambot.

**Option #2:**

Another approach would be, add one more hidden field called "js_fill". Now put JS code in your page which generates random value and fill in that field.

After this your server side check code would be like below:

```
if($_POST['js_fill'] != '' && $_POST['hidden_captcha'] == '') {
  // Valid Entry
} else {
  //Something Wring Here
}
```

Let me know if this is clear or needs more understanding in this concept.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with me! Well I have tried the hidden fields route but found that because this spam is just all blank entries then either way this hidden field would be blank anyway and thus the blank spam would still get through? If you see what I mean? Basically I can't check for entries in the hidden field because this spam is always blank anyway!

Comment: @CorrineJW I have modified approach in answer.

Comment: Yes I believe this will work perfectly! Thank you very much for your help.